# How can I set-up a custom formatter that uses target="_blank"?

Tags: 7, files, entities

I've installed the [Custom Formatters](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module, as I could not figure out why my View setting was not working for "Rewrite output" -> "Target" -> "_blank"

I need to recreate either the "Generic File" format or the "Rendered File" -> "Link" format.

This is what I've tried but I suppose 'attributes' is not something I can add for the $variables array in [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme/7) -

```
$output = '';
foreach ($variables['#items'] as $item) {
  $output .= theme('file_link', array(
    'file' => (object) $item,
    'attrs' => '_blank',
    ));
}
return $output;
```

That formatter code above was found on the CustomFormatters.com site for [Generic Image](http://customformatters.com/formatters/13/genericimage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found an answer that works for implementing the hook_file_link() function in the theme's template.php file:

Answer at https://drupal.org/node/301234#comment-4764468 - copied here:

```
function THEMENAME_file_link($variables) {
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

  $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
  $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' => $icon_directory));

  // Set options as per anchor format described at
  // http://microformats.org/wiki/file-format-examples
  $options = array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
    ),
  );

  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($file->description)) {
    $link_text = $file->filename;
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $file->description;
    $options['attributes']['title'] = check_plain($file->filename);
  }

  //open files of particular mime types in new window
  $new_window_mimetypes = array('application/pdf','text/plain');
  if (in_array($file->filemime, $new_window_mimetypes)) {
    $options['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
  }

  return '<span class="file">' . $icon . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span>';
}
```

Simply change THEMENAME to your theme name and place the code in the template file. I suppose I could extract this out into a custom formatter too.

Answer (score 0):

Implemente the filefield hook(function) in theme/template.php file
https://www.drupal.org/node/190566

```
<?php
function youtemplatename_filefield_file($file) {
  // Views may call this function with a NULL value, return an empty string.
  if (empty($file['fid'])) {
    return '';
  }

  $path = $file['filepath'];
  $url = file_create_url($path);
  $icon = theme('filefield_icon', $file);

  // Set options as per anchor format described at
  $options = array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'type' => $file['filemime'] . '; length=' . $file['filesize'],
    ),
  );

  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($file['data']['description'])) {
    $link_text = $file['filename'];
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $file['data']['description'];
    $options['attributes']['title'] = $file['filename'];
  }

  //open files of particular mime types in new window
  $new_window_mimetypes = array(
    'application/pdf',
    'text/plain'
  );
  if (in_array($file['filemime'], $new_window_mimetypes)) {
    $options['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
  }

  return '<div class="filefield-file clear-block">'. $icon . l($link_text, $url, $options) .'</div>';
}
?>
```